# After submit a curl request I got response Method Not Allowed

Tags: php

Method Not Allowed The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed
I want to delete data in REST API server by curl and Got reply Method Not Allowed. Why I got this Message?

Note :    $url_1 = API PATH

```
$reqpath = "contacts?expand=".$customer;
                $json ='';
                $url_1 = $path.$reqpath;
                $ch_1=curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
                curl_setopt($ch_1,CURLOPT_URL, $url_1);
                curl_setopt($ch_1,CURLOPT_POST,true);
                curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
                curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json));
                curl_setopt($ch_1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $result= curl_exec($ch_1);
                curl_close($ch_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's problem with your server configuration. 
Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/http.configuration.php under `http.request.methods.allowed` row. You need to add "DELETE" in this config.

Comment: Can I see this with phpinfo()?

Comment: Is there any way that I can configure this setting in .htaccess file ?

Comment: Look for the <Limit> and <LimitExcept> options in .htacces. I think they may help You.